# splitting a string misses the word which is used to split it

Tags: ruby

I have a string

```
a="Tamilnadu is far away from Kashmir"
```

If I split this string using "Tamilnadu", then I don't find Tamilnadu as a part of the array, I find empty string there, If I split the string "away" then away is not present in the result array, it's having empty string in the place of away. What should I do include it instead of having empty string.

Example

```
a="Tamilnadu is far away from Kashmir"

p a.split("Tamilnadu")
```

then Output is

```
["", " is far away from Kashmir"]
```

But I want

```
["Tamilnadu", " is far away from Kashmir"]
```

Comment: If you want to split after the first word, whatever it is: `a.split(/\s/,2)
 #=> ["Tamilnadu", "is far away from Kashmir"]`. This makes use of [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split)'s optional second argument.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, I know that. Infact, I started using that but my initial string is not a single word, it's `project = ccc` so I thought of asking this question, Amadan answer perfectly okay for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs:

> If pattern is a `Regexp`, `str` is divided where the pattern matches. Whenever the pattern matches a zero-length string, `str` is split into individual characters. If pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well.

So... to split by `"Tamilnadu"` and keep it in the list, make it a capture group:

```
"Tamilnadu is far away from Kashmir".split(/(Tamilnadu)/)
# => ["", "Tamilnadu", " is far away from Kashmir"]
```

or, if you want to split *after* `"Tamilnadu"`, make a zero-width match after it using lookbehind:

```
"Tamilnadu is far away from Kashmir".split(/(?<=Tamilnadu)/)
# => ["Tamilnadu", " is far away from Kashmir"]
```

Comment: `/(?<=Tamilnadu) /` to remove the leading space in `" is far..."`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The OP example has the space, so I left it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know where `"Tamilnadu"` is in the string but you want to split the string before and after it, and not have any empty strings in the resulting array, you can use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
def split_it(str, substring)
  str.scan(/\A.+(?= #{substring}\b)|\b#{substring}\b|(?<=\b#{substring} ).+/)
end
```

```
substring = "Tamilnadu"
```

```
split_it("Tamilnadu is far away from Kashmir", substring)
  #=> ["Tamilnadu", "is far away from Kashmir"] 
split_it("Far away is Tamilnadu from Kashmir", substring)
  #=> ["Far away is", "Tamilnadu", "from Kashmir"] 
split_it("Far away from Kashmir is Tamilnadu", substring)
  #=> ["Far away from Kashmir is", "Tamilnadu"] 
split_it("Far away is Daluth from Kashmir", substring)
  #=> []
split_it("Far away is Tamilnaduland from Kashmir", substring)
  #=> []
```

I've assumed that `substring` appears at most once in the string.

The regular expression can be written in free-spacing mode to make it self-documenting:

```
substring = "Tamilnadu"

/
\A.+                  # match the beginning of the string followed by > 0 characters     
(?=\ #{substring}\b)  # match the value of substring preceded by a space and
                      # followed by a word break, in a positive lookahead
|                     # or
\b#{substring}\b      # match the value of substring with a word break before and after
|                     # or
(?<=\b#{substring}\ ) # match the value of substring preceded by a word break 
                      # and followed by a space, in a positive lookbehind
.+                    # match > 0 characters
/x                    # free-spacing regex definition mode
  #=>
  /
  \A.+                  # ...
  (?=\ Tamilnadu\b)     # ...
  |                     # ...
  \bTamilnadu\b         # ...
  |                     # ...
  (?<=\bTamilnadu\ )    # ...
  .+                    # ...
  /x
```

Free-spacing mode removes all spaces before the regex is parsed, including spaces that may be intended to be part of the expression. It was for that reason that I escaped the two spaces. I could alternatively put each in a character class (`[ ]`) or use `\s`, `[[:space:]]` or `\p{Space}`, though they match whitespace, which is not quite the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The tricky thing for me is, I want split the string by project = projectname in which projectname is varible which receives value but in positive look ahead or positive look behind I can't pass such a variable.

Comment: That was not the question you asked, however. :-). I've edited my answer to generalize it slightly. Could you write, `projectname = "xyz"; split_it("When does project = xyz begin?", "project = #{projectname}") #=> ["When does", "project = xyz", "begin?"] `.

Comment: Yes I was not that much clear. Yeah your edit will work for me thanks